# Why can't I add to the model from a called method?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String stuff(
    @ModelAttribute("xxx") ReviewAB7500Data xxx,
    HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws GeneralDAOException {
    model.addAttribute("somekey",someValue);
 }
```

Everything works fine and I can see my object in my JSP. But when I change it up like this:

```
private void someOtherMethod(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("somekey",someValue);
    return;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String stuff(
    @ModelAttribute("xxx") ReviewAB7500Data xxx,
    HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws GeneralDAOException {
    someOtherMethod(model);
    return viewName;
 }
```

...the addtribute named "somekey" is never placed on the model, or at least it is not visible in my JSP. Any tips here?

Comment: I believe this should work fine.  This may sound like a stupid question, but what exactly does someOtherMethod look like?

Comment: This can't be right; there must be something else that has changed, or you've over-simplified the example before showing it to us.

Comment: I'd have to agree with the above comments.  Did you miss something while simplifying the logic?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add an extra parameter to that method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String stuff(@ModelAttribute("xxx") ReviewAB7500Data xxx,
                    BindingResult result,
                    HttpServletRequest request, 
                    Model model) throws GeneralDAOException
```

Comment: BindingResult is there, still the same issue.